# AngularJS: Load XML string to XML document

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, domparser

I have XML string, and I have to load it to DOM document.
I have tried this:

```
    if ($window.DOMParser)
    {
        parser=new $window.DOMParser();
        xml=parser.parseFromString(data,"application/xml");
    }
    else // Internet Explorer
    {
        xml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xml.async=false;
        xml.loadXML(data); 
    }
```

but on the angular controller.js it doesn't work!
I have gotten this:

```
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
    </div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror></body>
```

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have change the angular call to an XML call, and don't have to parse the response to document, because he is...
My call looks likes:

```
    $http({
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : "http://localhost:8080/getXML",
            timeout : 10000,
            params  : {
                fileName: fileName
            },
            transformResponse : function(data) {
                return $.parseXML(data);
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
           // data = document object
        });
```

from the API I return a valid XML string, and I defined the return type on Spring on the @RequestMapping to produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE.
Hope it will help also to you.